# Bearer Tokens / Role Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm issuing a bearer token for login. This contains the roles that the user belongs in. In my admin console I may add some users to new roles in real time. They may even already be logged in when this happens. If they are still logged in, then they're passing the old token, which still has the old roles, so the user is unauthorized for the new areas I just gave them access for in the admin console.

If the user just gets a new token (for example logging out and back in) then everything works.

I'm using OWIN and the .NET Membership provider in a Web API project

How would I update this in real time? I thought of two possibilities:

1. The user has to log out (and I can perhaps invalidate the token so 
   they have to ask for a new one)
2. Write custom code to check for the user roles each time a token is issued, regardless of what's in the token for roles

Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same problem.Did you get the solutions ? I think, we can use SinalR to track any role or claim changes into the server and it will inform the user that his roles has been changes or we can refresh the token without informing the user.